# Can't find .HTTP in JAVA.NET package

Tags: java, http, request

I want to use java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;
So I want to import this via

`import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;`

My Eclipse only finds the java.net Package and in there the following classes

- HttpCookie
- HttpRetryException
- HttpURLConnection

But it won't find the java.net.http and further on.

I tried to import it manually.

I tried to reinstall JDK (18) and JRE.

I fixed my JAVA_HOME path.

I looked if this was moved to another path in JDK 18.

But yet that didn't help.
What part am I missing?

Comment: I’m surprised it can’t also find `HttpRequest` In that package - and `BodyPublishers` is a static inner class of that one.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html

Comment: Sorry forget my previous comment - it looks like you are using Java 8, NOT Java 18;  can you confirm this?  It is a common mistake, since Java8 is also termed 1.8.   Java 8 does only have the classes you mention, so `HttpRequest` must have been added some time later.   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html

Comment: A Java [HTTP client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) was added to Java 11. That set of classes includes [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html). See the "_Since: 11_" note in the JavaDocs. This has not moved. It's still in the same package in Java 18, as noted in the previous @racraman comments. And yes, Java 1.8 equals Java 8 (due to marketing/branding renames, I believe); but 1.8 is different from the later Java 18.

Comment: Check Eclipse settings to see which Java version it's using. Even though you installed JDK 18 on your machine, it doesn't mean Eclipse is using it.

Comment: Arh... I made a fundamental mistake.
Thanks for the help. You basically set me on the correct path.
I had a JRE and JDK installed. Eclipse was using the JRE 1.8 (8) and not the JDK 18.
I had to add the JDK via Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Add 
and then tick the JDK to use this instead of the JRE.